# error with unknown path on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I am running a code on jupyter notebook using virtual machine (Ubuntu). Normally when there is an error it points to the file where the error is giving its path but I got an error with a path I do not have

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_84/10827517.py in <module>
----> 1 vae_cl.train(max_epochs=500, plan_kwargs=dict(weight_decay=0.0))

/tmp/ipykernel_84/1274271952.py in train(self, max_epochs, n_samples_per_label, check_val_every_n_epoch, train_size, validation_size, batch_size, use_gpu, plan_kwargs, **trainer_kwargs)
    187             use_gpu=use_gpu,
    188             check_val_every_n_epoch=check_val_every_n_epoch,
--> 189             **trainer_kwargs,
    190         )
    191         return runner()

/tmp/ipykernel_84/2912366039.py in __init__(self, model, training_plan, data_splitter, max_epochs, use_gpu, **trainer_kwargs)
     59         self.data_splitter = data_splitter
     60         self.model = model
---> 61         gpus, device = parse_use_gpu_arg(use_gpu)
     62         self.gpus = gpus
     63         self.device = device
```

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

What I noticed is that the function it is pointing to (---> 61) is actually in the file I am running but I do not understand why the path is like that '/tmp/ipykernel_84/1274271952.py'

Any idea?

Comment: That's the internal reference in ipykernel namespace it is using to run the code you have. Note how you see `/tmp/ipykernel_84/10827517.py` as the first line of the error? That last code you ran in your notebook `vae_cl.train(m...)` is triggering the error because what is getting sent in with `use_gpu` seems to cause `parse_use_gpu_arg()` to not work as expected? Just how the system is running and using Python's traceback system that is based originally on running scripts, and so it's internal representation follows that pattern. ...

Comment: <continued> That is probably running the first line of  code that is in that cell of your notebook with `vae_cl.train(m...)`. That 'path' is not meant for you to access.  First make sure you start your kernel fresh and try running the code again. It seems your code `parse_use_gpu_arg()` has more items it is returning than just the two you set up to deal with. Any chance you broke `use_gpu` or `parse_use_gpu_arg()` during your development? ...

Comment: <continued>  If you somehow clobbered `parse_use_gpu_arg()` or messed up what it returns mistakenly during developing, the a restart of the kernel and trying again may help. I'd also verify you are assigning `use_gpu` correct. And that your GPU is set up

Comment: I have a possible lead. Maybe? My suspicion is `rich` is involved. Possible? The way it's presenting for you looks slightly different, and so I'm not 100% sure yet. Normally rich makes nicer tracebacks but there is/was a bug that has crept in when using with Jupyter, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/traceback-wont-show-code-rather-no-such-file-or-directory-tmp-ipykernel/17460?u=fomightez) and [here](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/2271).

Comment: The more I look at it, the less convinced I am that this is related to `rich` use; however, I'll leave that comment for now. **That vague lead may though have been a dead end and not the cause/issue.** Still unclear why your traceback wasn't resolving the additional involved files clearly.