# I have some problems debugging with jupyter notebook's pdb

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

[image: Error]

I can't set breakpoint. My code is on the D drive, but the error said it was on the C drive.

At first, I thought I didn't save the code. So, I saved and reloaded the code, but the error occurred again.

Comment: please visit how to ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, don't add images

Comment: ⬆️ Please take this guys advice, he's doing god's work. Also take this bot's advice ⬇️

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Even though your notebook file is on the D drive. Jupyter and associated items are probably installed on the C drive, right? The kernel representation is thus on the C drive and that is what you are see. Note the `'ipykernel` in the path. Kernels are really what runs the code in a Juptyer notebook so you are seeing some internal info there. I don't know if it is an official temp file but you can consider it something like that. The note about the file not existing can be ignored. I have seen it recently. I'll try later to point you to other examples but point is that it isn't the cause.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had seen the "does not exist" stuff before. It may have even been in a traceback. However, I cannot find the example I'm thinking of. See my comments at the beginning of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74184582/8508004) about the path involving `tmp` and `ipykernel` from a traceback. **Maybe ultimately more pertinent to your issue**, it seemed as recently as end of 2022, something about breakpoint was broken. See [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/897). Suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60494988/8508004) may help you find an alternative way.